# Insert a text above a picture

Tags: diagrams, tikz-styles

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
% ~~~ some variations ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


\raisebox{9.5ex}{(a)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
    \node[text width=2cm, anchor=west, right] at (5,3)
{$\gamma \gamma \to \pi^+ \pi^-$};
        \node[shape=circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=20pt] (m) at ( 0, 0) {};
        \vertex (a) at ( 225:2cm) {};% <<< changed y-coordinate
        \vertex (b) at ( -45:2cm) {};%<<< switched to polar: -60 deg, 1 cm radius
        \vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
        \vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
        \diagram* {
            (a) -- [photon,color=red,edge label'=$q_2$] (m) % <<< funny bend
                -- [photon,color=red,edge   label'=$q_1$] (c),
            (b) -- [plain,edge label=$p_2$] (m) %<<< some color
                -- [plain, edge label=$p_1$] (d),
          };
    \end{feynman}
    
\end{tikzpicture}

 \raisebox{9.5ex}{=}


\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{feynman}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=20pt] (m) at ( 0, 0) {};
        \vertex (a) at ( 225:2cm) {};% <<< changed y-coordinate
        \vertex (b) at ( -45:2cm) {};%<<< switched to polar: -60 deg, 1 cm radius
        \vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
        \vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
        \diagram* {
            (a) -- [photon,color=red] (m) % <<< funny bend
                -- [photon,color=red] (c),
            (b) -- [plain] (m) %<<< some color
                -- [plain] (d),
          };
    \end{feynman}   
\end{tikzpicture}

\raisebox{9.5ex}{+}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=20pt] (m) at (0, 0) {};
\node[shape=rectangle,fill=black,draw=black] (n) at (3.1, 0) {\rule{0.5cm}{0.5cm}};
\vertex (a) at (225:2cm) {};
\vertex (b) at (-45:2cm) {};
\vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
\vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
\vertex (e) at ($(n) + (-45:2cm)$) {};
\vertex (f) at ($(n) + (45:2cm)$) {};

\diagram*{
(a) -- [photon,color=red] (m)
-- [photon,color=red] (c),
(n) -- [bend left=45, edge label=$\pi^-(K^-)$] (m)
-- [bend left=45, edge label=$\pi^+(K^+)$] (n),
(e) -- (n) -- (f),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

I need to add the formula $\gamma \gamma \to \pi^+ \pi^-$ above the picture; to this end, I defined it as a node. However, it distorts the picture and creates empty space between the first and second graphs. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- equation should be out of picture and above pictures
- to `standalone` options you should add option `varwidth=141mm`

```
\documentclass[border=3mm, varwidth=141mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\[
\gamma\gamma\to\pi^+\pi^-
\]

(a)
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{feynman}
        \node[shape=circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=20pt] (m) at ( 0, 0) {};
        \vertex (a) at ( 225:2cm) {};% <<< changed y-coordinate
        \vertex (b) at ( -45:2cm) {};%<<< switched to polar: -60 deg, 1 cm radius
        \vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
        \vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
        \diagram* {
            (a) -- [photon,color=red,edge label'=$q_2$] (m) % <<< funny bend
                -- [photon,color=red,edge   label'=$q_1$] (c),
            (b) -- [plain,edge label=$p_2$] (m) %<<< some color
                -- [plain, edge label=$p_1$] (d),
          };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   \begin{feynman}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=20pt] (m) at ( 0, 0) {};
        \vertex (a) at ( 225:2cm) {};% <<< changed y-coordinate
        \vertex (b) at ( -45:2cm) {};%<<< switched to polar: -60 deg, 1 cm radius
        \vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
        \vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
        \diagram* {
            (a) -- [photon,color=red] (m) % <<< funny bend
                -- [photon,color=red] (c),
            (b) -- [plain] (m) %<<< some color
                -- [plain] (d),
          };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{feynman}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=20pt] (m) at (0, 0) {};
        \node[shape=rectangle,fill=black,draw=black] (n) at (3.1, 0) {\rule{0.5cm}{0.5cm}};
        \vertex (a) at (225:2cm) {};
        \vertex (b) at (-45:2cm) {};
        \vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
        \vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
        \vertex (e) at ($(n) + (-45:2cm)$) {};
        \vertex (f) at ($(n) + (45:2cm)$) {};

        \diagram*{
        (a) -- [photon,color=red] (m)
        -- [photon,color=red] (c),
        (n) -- [bend left=45, edge label=$\pi^-(K^-)$] (m)
        -- [bend left=45, edge label=$\pi^+(K^+)$] (n),
        (e) -- (n) -- (f),
        };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

or use `article` document class, where you need to define sufficient large `\textwidth`,  for example by adding `\usepackage{geometry}` to document preamble and equation and picture insert in `center` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}  % <---
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}   
$
\gamma\gamma\to\pi^+\pi^-
$

(a)
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{feynman}
        \node[shape=circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=20pt] (m) at ( 0, 0) {};
        \vertex (a) at ( 225:2cm) {};% <<< changed y-coordinate
        \vertex (b) at ( -45:2cm) {};%<<< switched to polar: -60 deg, 1 cm radius
        \vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
        \vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
        \diagram* {
            (a) -- [photon,color=red,edge label'=$q_2$] (m) % <<< funny bend
                -- [photon,color=red,edge   label'=$q_1$] (c),
            (b) -- [plain,edge label=$p_2$] (m) %<<< some color
                -- [plain, edge label=$p_1$] (d),
          };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   \begin{feynman}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=20pt] (m) at ( 0, 0) {};
        \vertex (a) at ( 225:2cm) {};% <<< changed y-coordinate
        \vertex (b) at ( -45:2cm) {};%<<< switched to polar: -60 deg, 1 cm radius
        \vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
        \vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
        \diagram* {
            (a) -- [photon,color=red] (m) % <<< funny bend
                -- [photon,color=red] (c),
            (b) -- [plain] (m) %<<< some color
                -- [plain] (d),
          };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{feynman}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=20pt] (m) at (0, 0) {};
        \node[shape=rectangle,fill=black,draw=black] (n) at (3.1, 0) {\rule{0.5cm}{0.5cm}};
        \vertex (a) at (225:2cm) {};
        \vertex (b) at (-45:2cm) {};
        \vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
        \vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
        \vertex (e) at ($(n) + (-45:2cm)$) {};
        \vertex (f) at ($(n) + (45:2cm)$) {};

        \diagram*{
        (a) -- [photon,color=red] (m)
        -- [photon,color=red] (c),
        (n) -- [bend left=45, edge label=$\pi^-(K^-)$] (m)
        -- [bend left=45, edge label=$\pi^+(K^+)$] (n),
        (e) -- (n) -- (f),
        };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

In both cases you will get the same result:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the semplicity of the solution.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much!

Comment: @Samane, just write the `b` group of diagrams below `a`. BTW, instead of say "thanks" you can upvote answer or even accept it ... (by clicking on up-triangle and checkmark respectively at top left side of answer)  